# Thrift can not deserialize from json to java object

Tags: java, json, thrift, thrift-protocol

I generated a java object from the following thrift object:

```
struct Account {
    1: required string accountType,
    2: bool accountActive,
}
```

I wrote a java code trying to serialize java object to json string and then deserialize the json string back to java object. I can serialize successfully but failed to deserialize.

```
    TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(new TSimpleJSONProtocol.Factory());
    TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer(new TSimpleJSONProtocol.Factory());

    Account a1 = new Account();
    a1.setAccountType("P");
    a1.setAccountActive(true);

    String json = serializer.toString(a1);
    System.out.println(json);

    Account a2 = new Account();
    deserializer.deserialize(a2, json, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(a2);
    System.out.println(a2.getAccountType());
```

It keeps throwing the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'accountType' was not present! Struct: Account(accountType:null, accountActive:false)
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's the issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The json string result that serialized by thrift from java object is {"accountType":"P","accountActive":1}

Answer (score 3):

The `SimpleJSONProtocol` was never intended to be deserializable. Use `TJSONProtocol` instead.

From http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageJava:

> Serializing to "Simple" JSON
>
> ```
> TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(new TSimpleJSONProtocol.Factory());
> String json = serializer.toString(work);
> ```
>
> **The "Simple" JSON protocol produces output suitable for AJAX or scripting languages. It does not preserve Thrift's field tags and cannot be read back in by Thrift.**

(emphasis mine)