# Can't read the object back after write when set the parameter fieldNamesAsString_ is true with TJSONProtocol

Tags: java, thrift

```
CreateOrderRequest req = new CreateOrderRequest();

req.pid=1111;
req.name="xxx";

TMemoryBuffer mem_buf = new TMemoryBuffer(512);
TJSONProtocol bin_proto = new TJSONProtocol(mem_buf,true);

try
{
    req.write(bin_proto);
    System.out.println("====begin serial json=================");
    String jsonStr=mem_buf.toString("utf-8");
    System.out.println("after jasonprocol="+jsonStr);

    System.out.println("====begin deserial json=================");
    CreateOrderRequest req2 = new CreateOrderRequest();
    TMemoryBuffer mem_buf2 = new TMemoryBuffer(512);  
    byte[] data = jsonStr.getBytes();
    mem_buf2.write(data);

    TJSONProtocol bin_proto2 = new TJSONProtocol(mem_buf2,true);
    req2.read(bin_proto2);
    System.out.println("after de jasonprocol pid="+req.pid);
    System.out.println("after de jasonprocol name="+req.name);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

output:

```
====begin serial json=================

after jasonprocol={"pid":{"i32":1111},"uid":{"i32":0},"corpId":  {"i32":0},"sharePriceE6":{"i64":0},"shareCount":{"i32":0},"totalPriceE6":{"i64":0},"bankcardId":{"i32":0},"name":{"str":"xxx"},"isAnonymous":{"tf":0},"expectIncomeE6":{"i64":0},"clientId":{"i32":0},"totalAmtE6":{"i64":0},"subSrc":{"str":""}}
====begin deserial json=================

org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Unexpected character:p
```

**Question**:

If the fieldNamesAsString_ is not set true, then `jasonStr` becomes `{"1":  {"i32":1111},"2":{"i32":0},"3":{"i32":0},...` and can be written back to CreateOrderRequest, I don't think it is reasonable.

You can write a object to a json str,but can't read back?

Answer (score 0):

The `fieldNamesAsString` parameter leads to exactly the same effect: a write-only JSON format. You just can't read that kind of JSON back using Thrift, by design.

So in essence this is somewhat similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319325/thrift-can-not-deserialize-from-json-to-java-object), albeit not exactly the same problem.

> you can write a object to a json str,but can't read back?

Yes, that's the intention here. Obviously there are people who have a use case for it.

Further reading:

- [THRIFT-3235 TJSONProtocol when serialized yields TField ids rather than names](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3235)
- [THRIFT-3232 Cannot deserialize json messages created with fieldNamesAsString](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3232)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but i think it won't be very complex to implement the deserialize  method,and why not do it?because the TField stored both the thriftId and fiedName,

Comment: @robin. "*i think it won't be very complex to implement*"  -- This is open source, so just fire away! [You're more than welcome to provide a pull request](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute).